# _redirect not working in catch block in magento

Tags: magento

```
$uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);
$uploader->save($path, $fname); //save the file on the specified path
$post['simagepath'] = $fname;
  }
} catch (Exception $e) {
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($e->getMessage() . " please upload only valid extension file: jpg, png, gif, jpeg");
$this->_redirect('advert/banner/list');
//echo "test";                
}
die("hello");
Mage::getModel('advert/advert')->saveAdvert($post);
$this->_redirect('advert/banner/list');
```

Above code is just part of code but not full code.
In this code, in catch block redirect function not working,any one can help me why it not working in magento.

Answer (score 4):

Where is this code? If this is in a controller, most likely you need to `return;` right after `$this->_redirect('advert/banner/list');` to exit the code and subsequently the redirect will / should execute.

Comment: It's working !! May I know wat is the prbm, why it's not working without `return`